# Issue while installing security patch in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-10266

I am trying to install the patch but it throwing an error like below, kindly tell me how to solve this issue

> - $'\r'PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2017-09-13-06-37-37.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
>     PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2017-09-13-06-37-37.sh: line 9: syntax
>     error near unexpected token
>     `$'{\r'''ATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-201709-13-06-37-37.sh:line9:`_check_installed_tools(){

Answer (score 0):

Its may be wrong command used. Try following steps

Steps to apply patch

1. Download patch SUPEE-10266 for your current magento version(eg:1.9.2.4)
2. Paste the patch file into the root path of the project
3. In command prompt, go to your project root.
4. Then type sh PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2017-09-13-06-27-12.sh
5. Enter